# TikZ : issue between odd-even rule and [rotate=angle]

Tags: tikz-pgf

While creating exercises with Venn diagrams intersections, a problem occured  with masking when a pattern is defined with a rotation.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\ellipseA{(0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt)}
\def\ellipseB{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseB \ellipseA ;
    \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the small ellipse is correctly masking, but the rotation also affect the big ellipse while masking (but not while drawing the outline).
This is confusing, but I'm sure someone knows exactly what to do to fix this.

I also tried to use scopes to avoid this issue, but with no positive effect until now.

edit:

A bit more to the weird thing, if I add a rotation to the big ellipse, then the issue is way more confusing:

```
\def\ellipseA{[rotate=20] (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt)}
\def\ellipseB{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseB \ellipseA ;
   \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the effect of your `rotate` option, you should use scopes (via `{}`) into your paths. Ex:

```
\fill[cyan,even odd rule] { \ellipseB } { \ellipseA } ;
```

Or use scopes into the definition of your ellipses:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\ellipseA{(0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt)}
  \def\ellipseB{{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt)}}
  \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseB \ellipseA ;
  \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\ellipseA{{[rotate=20] (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt)}}
  \def\ellipseB{{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt)}}
  \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseB \ellipseA ;
  \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is just to say that it does not matter whether or not you put the cut part first or last. The issue is that the transformations, i.e. rotations in this case, accumulate. So the second drawing still inherits the rotation of the first one. One way to avoid this is to use some "adjoint" transformation

```
\def\ellipseA{[rotate=20] (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt) [rotate=-20]}
\def\ellipseB{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt) [rotate=-45]}
```

where you undo the rotation after adding the path, then the order does not matter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\ellipseA{[rotate=20] (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt) [rotate=-20]}
    \def\ellipseB{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt) [rotate=-45]}
  \begin{scope} 
    \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseB \ellipseA ;
    \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
  \end{scope}   
  \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm] 
    \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
    \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
  \end{scope}   
  \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm] 
    \draw[fill=cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
  \end{scope}   
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm] 
    \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
    \draw[fill=cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
  \end{scope}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The last two examples show that you do not need separate `\draw` and `\fill` paths here.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm dumb maybe.
I just used the even odd rule upside down.
You have to put the cut out part after the masked part in order to make it work ;)

```
\def\ellipseA{[rotate=20] (0,0) ellipse (20pt and 30pt)}
\def\ellipseB{[rotate=45] (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 20pt)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[cyan,even odd rule] \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
    \draw \ellipseA \ellipseB ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Sorry for the stupid question, if necessary, mods can delete it, event if I think it could be useful to those making the same mistake in the future.